# using bits manipulation reduce cache expense

Tags: c, bit-manipulation, mmap

I have to  use only 5 bit MSB data from each 12 bit data , I have to take 64 bit at a time for cache optimization and use bit manipulation to get 5 MSB bits for each 12 bit pixel,I am not getting , How should I achieve this ? 
 This is code I wrote and working properly but rather than taking 8 bit at a time(buffer is 8bit pointer) I have to take 64 bits .  In buffer I have pointed complete file. *This code is to make a histogram.

Taking LITTLE ENDIAN into consideration

Answer (score 1):

64 bits isn't a nice multiple of 12 bits. To fix that, read a group of three 64-bit values (16 pixels) at a time. E.g.:

```
    uint64_t v1 = (uint64_t *)(&buffer[pos]);
    uint64_t v2 = (uint64_t *)(&buffer[pos+8]);
    uint64_t v3 = (uint64_t *)(&buffer[pos+16]);
```

Then you can do all the masking at once:

```
    v1 &= 0x0F80F80F80F80F80ULL;
    v2 &= 0x80F80F80F80F80F8ULL;
    v3 &= 0xF80F80F80F80F80FULL;
```

For the first 5 pixels its just shifting to separate the individual pixel values (`uint16_t MSBs = v1; v1 >>= 12;` repeated 5 times). For the 6th pixel you need to do some fudging (`MSBs = v2 << 4; v2 >>= 8;`), then for the next 4 pixels it's back to `MSBs = v2; v2 >>= 12;` repeated 4 times. For the pixel after that it's a little more fudging (`MSBs = v2 | (v3 << 8)`); then it's just more `MSBs = v3; v3 >>= 12;` repeated 5 times to finish the group of 16 pixels.

Note that this is likely to be the fastest possible way; because there's no branches (and no chance of expensive branch mispredictions), because the CPU can do most of the operations in parallel (especially if you fully expand the pixel extraction to get rid of the shifts), and because the "fetch and mask" phase is well suited to SIMD techniques.

Comment: ,what is ULL? can u explain more clearly ? I think using this will make me to calculate 24 pixels at a time and I will loose data at end of each coloumn (i.e. 4096 /24 = 170.5)?
a code will make things more clear(thanks for ur time).

Comment: does htobe64() increases time to run ?

Comment: @kancha: The `ULL` suffix tells the compiler that the number should be treated as an "unsigned long long" - without it the compiler will treat it as an "int" and it probably won't fit in an "int" so that'd be bad. `htobe64()` should either cost nothing (because host is big-endian anyway) or will depend on which CPU it is (e.g. very cheap on 64-bit 80x86 because it'd be a single `bswap` instruction, a bit more expensive on 32-bit 80x86 because it'd have to be split into two 32-bit halves, maybe like `bswap edx; bswap eax; xchg edx,eax`).

Comment: @Brendan ,okay thanks got your point  . I am using ARM processor will htobe64() cost me now a significant amount? Please,  Can I get reference code or source of what you have explained above?

Comment: I don't know much about ARM; but it looks like there's a "`rev` - reverse byte order in 32-bit word" instruction in at least one of their instruction sets. I wouldn't be too surprised if it ends up similar to 80x86 (cheap for 64-bit ARM, a bit less cheap for 32-bit ARM)